# How to make scroll more smooth in react-native

Tags: scroll, react-native

I was wondering is it possible to make the scroll to top more smooth. What attributes should one add to make it more smooth (NOT to fast).

here is my implementation:

```
scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({y: 0, animated: true});
```

Answer (score 0):

There‘s a prop called scrollThrottle. You should look for it in the documentation for more details